# Can't connect to a VNC server

Tags: networking, ssh, vnc, wsl2

I can connect to a VNC server from my home Windows 10 machine, but not from my Windows 10 laptop.

On my home machine I open SSH tunnel in WSL to secure VNC connection:

```
ssh -L 59000:localhost:5901 -C -N -l <username> $VNC_IP
```

and run UltraVNC client:

[image]

that connects successfully and the following messages appear in `/home/<user>/.vnc/localhost:1.log` on the server:

```
31/08/23 08:36:05 Got connection from client 127.0.0.1
31/08/23 08:36:12 rfbProcessClientProtocolVersion: client gone
31/08/23 08:36:12 Client 127.0.0.1 gone
31/08/23 08:36:12 Statistics:
31/08/23 08:36:12   framebuffer updates 0, rectangles 0, bytes 0
Xlib:  extension "DPMS" missing on display ":1.0".
```

But when I do the same on my laptop I can't connect neither with UltriVNC nor with TightVNC:

[image]

[image]

and no messages appear in VNC log `/home/<user>/.vnc/localhost:1.log` on the server.

On both laptop and my home machine I am able to connect with `telnet` from WSL:

```
$ telnet localhost 59000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
RFB 003.008
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

also I check SSH tunnel as follows:

```
$ netstat -lpnt
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59000         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29880/ssh
tcp6       0      0 ::1:59000               :::*                    LISTEN      29880/ssh
```

what can be the difference between my laptop and my home machine?

Turning Firewall off does not help:

[image]

does it mean that it is a server problem? What else can prevent the connection?

**EDIT1**

Did the following experiment:

disabled firewall on the server:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

and was able to connect from the laptop directly to the server (without SSH tunnel):

[image]

is it possible that SSH tunnels conflict with each other?

**EDIT2**

Rebooted the laptop and SSH tunnel started to work and I was able to connect to VNC server:

[image]

Comment: Unclear : Do you mean that when SSH from one computer succeeds, SSH from the other is blocked?

Comment: @harrymc from the home machine SSH succeeds, but it is not clear what happens with SSH on the laptop. I can do `telnet localhost 59000` - does it mean that SSH works?

Comment: The SSH server by default listens on port 22.

Comment: @harrymc port 22 succeeds